# Why do I get a Kill:9 error whilst running STAR?

Tags: indexing, macos-catalina, genome

I am trying to generate a genome index with STAR but whenever I run the commands from STAR it after a while prints kill:9 . I havnt been able to understand why it is doing this?  Any advice or tips? Many thanks!

Comment: `Kill 9` means Force kill/end a process. Sounds like it tries to end a process, but why you see this is unsure and must be a bug.

Comment: do you know how I would go about finding out why it killed it?